# How many Developer Tools windows can I open in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: multiple-instances, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

Is there any limit on the number of developer tools windows in Microsoft Edge? I'm unable to open more than one developer tools window.

I've a main window and a popout window, but I'm not able to open more than one developer tools window. But I need to check for errors in both the pages simultaneously on triggering an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one developer tool window per page/tab and it can either be docked or undocked (popout). If you have many tabs open though you can also have many developer tool windows. Up to 1 per tab. Let me know if that's not what you're seeing so we can get a bug on it.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I get one developer tool per window, but at times I'm unable to open the second developer window. The website I'm using is not really fully compatible with Edge and I see a surge in RAM usage. Hence, Edge basically hangs and that might be one reason why the second window doesn't open. Edge version 20.10240. Thoughts?